# Getting poor answers, what should I do?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

My question is here: [How to call Activities from a non-Activity Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945504/how-to-call-activities-from-a-non-activity-thread)

I have edited my question a few times, always trying to improve it to help others help me. I have it edited in such a way that it is super tight and to the point.

I tried commenting with the two answers I received. However, without offending anyone, the answers don't solve anything. One of them started as a link only answer, then improved a bit, but still it is a just recyclable material from other places that was not even tested (at one point it wasn't even compilable code).

I found a post that is extremely relevant, but still it escapes me how to make it work with my code, I posted that into my question as well.

---

Can I have some tips on how to make *that* particular question better? Should I downvote the answers that don't solve my question, even though they tried (aware of [downvote rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down))? Or should I just wait until I can put a bounty on it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the answers are poor quality and aren't useful then down-vote them. This seems to have a better "rate of return" than just commenting on the answer.

Don't worry about the 1 point of rep it will cost you. If the answerer improves their answer you can retract the down-vote and get the rep back. If the answerer deletes their answer you will get the rep back.

Comment: One of the answerers didn't like it, but I will take your advice to heart. Thank you.